# Constructing a POVM to discriminate $m$ quantum states. What if they're linearly dependent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space

I've come across this problem in Nielsen & Chuang's Quantum Information book (problem 2.64)

Suppose Bob is given a quantum state chosen from a set $|ψ_1 \rangle, . . . , |ψ_m\rangle$
of linearly independent states. Construct a POVM $\{E_1, E_2, . . ., E_{m+1}\}$ such that
if outcome $E_i$ occurs, $1 ≤ i ≤ m$, then Bob knows with certainty that he was
given the state $|ψ_i\rangle$. (The POVM must be such that $\langle ψ_i|E_i|ψ_i \rangle > 0$ for each $i$.)

This is my proposed solution:

Denote by $|\phi_i\rangle$ the (unique? I guess it doesn't matter) vector orthogonal to the subspace spanned by $\{ | \psi_j \rangle \}_{j \neq i}$ and define

$$E_i = \sum_{i\neq j} | \phi_j \rangle \langle\phi_j |$$

Then $\langle \psi_j | E_i | \psi_j\rangle = 0$ by construction, and $\langle \psi_i | E_i | \psi_i\rangle > 0$. The last operator is defined to satisfy completeness:

$$E_{m+1} = \mathbb{I} - \sum_{j=1}^m E_j.$$

So, when get gets outcome $i$, he knows it can't have been any of the other $\psi_j$'s, so it must have been $\psi_i$ for sure. If he gets outcome $m+1$, he doesn't know anything. Is this correct?

What happens if now we introduce another vector to the set: $\psi \rangle = a |ψ_1 \rangle + b |ψ_2 \rangle$, i.e. drop the linear independence condition (just on a simple example here). How would that affect the $E_j$'s, is it still possible to construct a POVM like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A crucial hypothesis is missed in your construction.

*Each $\phi_i$ must also satisfy $\phi_i \not \perp \psi_i$, otherwise $\langle \psi_i |E_i \psi_i\rangle >0$ is false.*

This point provides an answer to your last question as well.

If $\psi$ is an added further vector, linearly **dependent** on the vectors $\psi_i$, the construction you made cannot be re-proposed as the constraint I pointed out cannot be satisfied. Indeed, even if the correspondingly added normalized vector $\phi$ is orthogonal to all $\psi_i$, it is (evidently) impossible that $\phi \not \perp \psi = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \psi_i$.

Comment: So how do I guarantee that $\phi_i \not \perp \psi_i$ in my construction? I  thought this was always the case - I was visualizing the situation as a plane in 3D space (subspace spanned by $i \neq j$) and a perpendicular vector to it ($\phi_i$). This vector can never be itself perpendicular to any other vector that's not contained inside the plane. I thought this generalized to the case of a $m-1$ dimensional subspace of an $m$ dim. space?

Comment: Suppose that the space has $m+q$ dimensions with $q>0$ (as you generally assume when supposing that $E_{m+1}\neq 0$). In this case there necessarily exist a vector $\phi$ which is simultaneously orthogonal to the space spanned by all the $m$ vectors $\psi_i$, thus it is orthogonal to all every $\psi_i$ with $i=1,\ldots, m$. It happens  even if they are linearly independent. Therefore it is not always the case and you should pick out the $\phi_i$ imposing *also* the hypothesis I pointed out. It is always possible. However it is *not* possible, if the $\psi_i$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: But in this construction, the space has dimension $m$ and all of these subspaces are $m-1$ dimensional, so I don't see how this applies here.

Comment: Are you saying that you also assume that the space has dimension $m$ from scratch?

Comment: It seems that I was indeed assuming that, and for no reason. The question doesn't mention the dimensionality of space at all (though presumably it should be finite-dimensional)... now I understand your point

Comment: OK, if you assume that, my constraint is automatically satisfied, but my final remark (in my answer) holds true anyway when considering linearly dependent vectors. My point is that if you assume that $E_{m+1}\neq 0$ in general, the space may have dimension $>m$, as it is evident in the case  $\phi_i \perp \phi_j$ for $i\neq j$ since your POVM becomes a PVM with $n>m$ orthogonal projectors.

Answer (score 3):

The implicit context of this exercise is some Hilbert space $H$ of dimension at least $m$. Let $W$ be the ($m$-dimensional) subspace of $H$ spanned by the set $\{|\psi_1\rangle, ..., |\psi_m\rangle\}$ and let, for each $i=1,...,m$, $V_i$ be the ($m-1$ dimensional) subspace of $W$ spanned by the set $\{|\psi_{j}\rangle \mid j \neq i\}$.

From elementary Hilbert space theory we know that each of the vectors $|\psi_i\rangle$ can be split up into a sum $|\psi_i\rangle = |v_i\rangle + |o_i\rangle$, where $|v_i\rangle \in V_i$ and $|o_i\rangle \in V_i^\perp \cap W$ ($|v_i\rangle$ is the orthogonal projection of $|\psi_i\rangle$ onto $V_i$ and $|o_i\rangle = |\psi_i\rangle - |v_i\rangle)$. Note that $|o_i\rangle \neq 0$ for each $i$, as $|\psi_i \rangle$ by the assumption of linear independence does not belong to $V_i$.

Now let $E_i=\frac{|o_i\rangle\langle o_i|}{m+1}$, for $i=1,...,m$, and let $E_{m+1} = I - \sum_{j=1}^m E_j$. Then it's an easy check that set of operators $\{E_1, ...,E_{m+1}\}$ satisfies the requirements for a POVM (the factors $\frac{1}{m+1}$ are to make sure that $E_{m+1}$ stays positive). Furthermore, for $1\leq i, k \leq m$ with $i\neq k$, we have $\langle\psi_k|E_i|\psi_k\rangle = 0$, and

$$\langle\psi_i|E_i|\psi_i\rangle = \frac{1}{m+1}\big( \langle v_i|o_i\rangle + \langle o_i|v_i\rangle + 2\langle o_i|o_i\rangle \big) = \frac{2}{m+1}\langle o_i|o_i\rangle>0,$$ as wanted.

Comment: There is something that I think is necessary still. How does Bob know which $E_i$ took? Also if $\langle o_i|o_i\rangle$ are equal for two values of $i$ (the extreme case would be that the set $\lbrace |\Psi_i\rangle\rbrace$ is orthonormal), how can Bob determine which $|\Psi_i\rangle$ he has measured?

Comment: I think one needs instead $E_i=\frac{|o_i\rangle \langle o_i|}{i+1}$.

Comment: To make sure $E_{m+1}$ stays positive, $E_i$ needs to be defined as $E_i=\frac{|o_i\rangle\langle o_i|}{m\langle o_i|o_i\rangle}$.

Comment: Let me show why this is so. Assume $w\in W$ is an arbitrary vector from $W$. Then $\langle w|E_i|w\rangle=\frac{\langle w|o_i\rangle\langle o_i|w\rangle}{m\langle o_i|o_i\rangle}=\frac{|\langle o_i|w\rangle|^2}{m\langle o_i|o_i\rangle}$. This is obviously $>0$, so $E_i$ for $i \le m$ is positive, as required. Now, $\langle w|E_{m+1}|w\rangle=\langle w|w\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{|\langle o_i|w\rangle|^2}{m\langle o_i|o_i\rangle}$.

Comment: By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle o_i|w\rangle|^2\le\langle o_i|o_i\rangle\langle w|w\rangle$, so $\langle w|E_{m+1}|w\rangle\ge\langle w|w\rangle-\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\langle o_i|o_i\rangle\langle w|w\rangle}{m\langle o_i|o_i\rangle}=\langle w|w\rangle-\langle w|w\rangle=0$, so $E_{m+1}$ is positive, as required.

Comment: Note that vectors $|o_i\rangle$ are not normalized, so $\langle o_i|o_i\rangle$ does not have to be $1$, which means this inequality would not hold without the factor of $\langle o_i|o_i\rangle$ in the denominator. Another thing different in my definition is usage of $m$, instead of $m+1$. $m+1$ works too, but $+1$ there is unnecessary.

Comment: @user2820579 Bob does not need to decide which $E_i$ to take. A measurement is mathematically described by a collection of operators $E_i$ associated with each measurement outcome, but the physical act of measurement is just a single action, giving one of the measurement outcomes $E_i$ randomly, depending on the state being measured.